# Turing Machine, Strings and Sub-String

Tags: turing-machines

What is the best way to design a Turing machine that accepts W1#W2 where W2 is a substring of W1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, and works best when your questions are about specific problems with specific code samples (or in this case, algorithms). Can you share what you've tried to far to solve this problem? Can you elaborate on what's wrong with the solution you've already attempted? What is your level of familiarity with Turing machines (as the level of detail needed to answer this question for you will depend on how comfortable you are with certain TM idioms, such as extending the tape alphabet through "marking")?

Answer (score 1):

Here is brute-force solution for a single-sided single-tape Turing machine: for each i, mark symbol i in W1 and see if W1[i…|W2|+i] = W2[1…|W2|].

To check, bounce back and forth between W1 and W2, marking the corresponding symbols as long as they match, and resetting them in the event you find a discrepancy.

Processing in the case of no match might look like the following:

```
abc#abd    Xbc#abd    Xbc#abd    Xbc#abd    Xbc#abd    Xbc#Abd
^           ^           ^           ^           ^         ^ 
mark        scan        scan        scan        scan      mark'


Xbc#Abd    Xbc#Abd    Xbc#Abd    Xbc#Abd    XBc#Abd    XBc#Abd
  ^         ^         ^           ^           ^           ^
  scan'     scan'     scan'       bounce      mark'       scan


XBc#Abd    XBc#Abd    XBc#ABd    XBc#ABd    XBc#ABd    XBc#ABd
    ^           ^         ^         ^         ^         ^
    scan        scan      mark'     scan'     scan'     scan'


XBc#ABd    XBC#ABd    XBC#ABd    XBC#ABd    XBC#ABd    XBC#ABd
  ^           ^           ^           ^           ^         ^
  bounce      mark'       scan        scan        scan     reset


XBC#Abd    XBC#abd    XBC#abd    XBc#abd    Xbc#abd    Xbc#abd
    ^         ^         ^         ^         ^           ^
    reset     reset     reset     reset     reset       mark


XYc#abd ...
  ^
  scan
```

This will accept if you run out of unmarked symbols in W2 at the same time as you run out of unmarked symbols in W1, or earlier. Otherwise, you'll keep resetting until you've confirmed there is no first-marked symbol in W1 that works and you've marked them all.